# Redirect WindowsMessages received by the parrent window to the related ChildWindow

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I’m trying to wrap the winapi into my own classes like CWindow, CButton, CListBox, etc. So every class has its own CALLBACK memberfunction and therefore I subclassed every child windowcontrol to make them use their own callback. Sadly I figured out that not all windowmessages are sent to my subclassed callback function. For example some child controls like the ListBox control don’t receive the WM_COMMAND messages. 
Now I’m searching for a way to redirect all windowmessages which relate to a child window to the childwindo's callback. Cause my code is  a bit too long I created a short example code for a parentwindow class and a childcontrol class (not completed). The goal is to redirect all windowmessages which the parentwindow receive to the related childcontrol callback.

```
class CWindow {  //Parent Window example
private:
    HWND hParrent;
public:
    CWindow(){
        hParrent = CreateWindowExA(...); //with WS_CLIPCHILDREN style
    }
    static LRESULT CALLBACK ParentCallback(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
        if (IsWindow((HWND)lParam) && hWnd != (HWND)lParam)  
            return SendMessageA((HWND)lParam, message, wParam, lParam); //Seems lParam often stores the child HWND. So idea is to redirect the messages to the childWindow. Avoid selfcalls with "hWnd != (HWND)lParam" cause after SendMessageA lparam and hwnd is the same... but currently this idea seems not working
        else{
            switch (message){} //do something 
            return DefWindowProcA(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    //some other member functions
};

class CButton { //Child WindowControl example
private:    
    HWND hChild;
    WNDPROC oldWndProc;
public:
    CButton(){
        hChild = CreateWindowExA(...); //with WS_CHILD and WS_CLIPSIBLINGS styles
        oldWndProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtrA(hChild, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)ChildCallback); 
    }
    static LRESULT CALLBACK ChildCallback(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
        switch(message){}  //do something
        if (oldWndProc != NULL)
            return CallWindowProcA(oldWndProc, hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);  
        else
        return DefWindowProcA(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    //some other member functions 
};
```

Comment: `I’m trying to wrap the winapi into my own classes like CWindow, CButton, CListBox, etc`  Unless you've mastered the vanilla `C` Windows API, this is not an easy undertaking.   There are nuances, tricks, etc. that you have to be aware of before designing things like this.  Why not look at existing frameworks to see how they accomplish this?

Comment: Also, in your title you say "subclass".  That word has two definitions w.r.t the Windows API as opposed to C++.  Windows subclassing is an aspect of the Windows API, and a C++ "subclass" would mean taking a base C++ class and deriving from it.

Comment: It's only on a small project where the task is to creat a little gui with some buttons, edit controls etc. not much. The most stuff is already done, i have buttons, and the other controls and it works.. only problem is now that my child controls not receive all needed windowsmessage.. for e.x. the listbox dont receive the needed WM_COMMAND message. If i could get this message redirected to the related child controls i think my project is finish then.

Comment: Why would a Listbox control ever want to handle `WM_COMMAND` messages? Those are notifications meant for the parent, to inform the parent about events inside the Listbox control, so that the parent can perform additional actions. You've got things severely backwards if you think otherwise.

Comment: Like I said, unless you have mastered the Windows API, *any* undertaking of trying to "object-orient" the Win32 API is not a small matter.  Doesn't matter if it's just a few controls -- just one or two controls that do things differently or require different handling can set you back.   See here:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32/VU_-47CLi5c/aFytYvdyQ50J and here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/02/542115.aspx

Comment: Y you' are right. After several months of working and learning with the winapi i got it now too. Its not an easy task...especially for newbies^^. I read some books and there they only showed the basics how to create a button, window,.. but never how to creat a good software architecture. I'm still in school and learning some basics of OOP in java. So i thought i will wrap some winapi stuff into classes and make them useable like in java (JButton button = new JButton(..);). Finaly the time is over. I wraped some stuff and its working for my needs. Only some Windows messages are missed.

Comment: Cause i cant rewrite the whole project or creat a newone by using a framework i have tofinish that project. Finaly i got it working to redirect the most needed messages back to the child control callback. Currently i use that code: `if (IsWindow((HWND)lParam) && hWnd != (HWND)lParam) return SendMessageA((HWND)lParam, message, wParam, NULL);`            If somone has the knowhow if im doing a fatal misstake (maybe infinity massage circles) by using this code in the parrent callback then let me know. Currently it seems that everything works fine and my child controls recieve the needed messages.

Comment: K in general I would not recommend my code to use it for all WM  messages because the value of lParam is depending on the messasge. Finaly I use it only in WM_COMMAND cases where i know that the lParam can be a handle to the child control... and to be more safe i hold all my child controls in an array to compare if the (HWND)lParam is realy an element of my child controls in the array. I know its not a good code design but in my case i have no other choice anymore.

Comment: This is exactly how you have to do it. It also works for `WM_NOTIFY`.